# Having trouble reading a struct with a vector<string> from a binary file

Tags: c++, vector, struct, binary, binaryfiles

I'm making my OOP final project and part of it is to make a couple of databases, I'm having trouble with this one.

Every time an `Alquiler x` is made, it needs to go to the database's `vector<Alquiler>`, and then stored in a binary file. Problem is that I'm probably managing the sizes wrong because once I add a couple of `Alquiler`, the array gets filled up with rubbish, always outputting random characters.

Here's the code, I tried to compact it as much as possible and just leave the relevant part. If anyone wants to take a look I'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int day, month, year;
};

struct structalquiler
{
    int dni, totalq, dep;
    int faday, famonth, fayear;
    int fdday, fdmonth, fdyear;
    vector<string> artlist;
};

class Alquiler {
private:
    
    int a_DNI_Cliente;
    int a_Total_Alquiler, a_Deposito;
    Date a_Date_Alquiler, a_Date_Devolucion;
    vector<string> a_Article_list;
    
public:

    Alquiler ();
    Alquiler (int dni, int totalq, int dep, Date fa, Date fd, vector<string> arts);

    void save(ofstream &outfile) {                      // Bin file writing
        structalquiler reg;
        reg.dni = a_DNI_Cliente;
        reg.dep = a_Deposito;
        reg.totalq = a_Total_Alquiler;
        reg.faday = a_Date_Alquiler.day;
        reg.famonth = a_Date_Alquiler.month;
        reg.fayear = a_Date_Alquiler.year;
        reg.fdday = a_Date_Devolucion.day;
        reg.fdmonth = a_Date_Devolucion.month;
        reg.fdyear = a_Date_Devolucion.year;
        reg.artlist = a_Article_list;

        int wo_size = sizeof(reg) - sizeof(reg.artlist);

        outfile.write((char*)&reg, wo_size);

        int size = reg.artlist.size();              // Writing of the vector<string>
        outfile.write((char*)&size, sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int letter_amount = reg.artlist[i].length();
            outfile.write((char*)&letter_amount, sizeof(int));
            outfile.write(reg.artlist[i].c_str(), letter_amount);
        }
        
    }

    void read(ifstream &infile) {                           // Reading of the file
        structalquiler reg;
        int wo_size = sizeof(reg) - sizeof(reg.artlist);
        infile.read((char*)&reg, wo_size);

        a_DNI_Cliente = reg.dni;
        a_Deposito = reg.dep;
        a_Total_Alquiler = reg.totalq;
        a_Date_Alquiler.day = reg.faday;
        a_Date_Alquiler.month = reg.famonth;
        a_Date_Alquiler.year = reg.fayear;
        a_Date_Devolucion.day = reg.fdday;
        a_Date_Devolucion.month = reg.fdmonth;
        a_Date_Devolucion.year = reg.fdyear;
        // a_Article_list = reg.artlist;

        vector<string> v;                                   // Reading of the vector<string>
        int read_size;
        infile.read((char*)&read_size, sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < read_size; i++)
        {
            int letter_amount;
            infile.read((char*)&letter_amount, sizeof(int));
            char* buffer = new char[letter_amount + 1];
            infile.read(buffer, letter_amount);
            buffer[letter_amount] = '\0';
            v.push_back(string(buffer));
            delete [] buffer;

        }
        
        a_Article_list = v;
    }


};

Alquiler::Alquiler(){}
Alquiler::Alquiler(int dni, int totalq, int dep, Date fa, Date fd, vector<string> arts)
        : a_DNI_Cliente(dni), a_Total_Alquiler(totalq), a_Deposito(dep), a_Date_Alquiler(fa), a_Date_Devolucion(fd), a_Article_list(arts) {}

class Database {
private:
    string m_file_name = "alquileres.dat";
    vector<Alquiler> Arreglo_Alquileres;
public:

    Database() {                                                                // storing in the vector<Alquiler>
        ifstream infile(m_file_name.c_str(), ios::binary|ios::ate);
        if (infile.is_open())
        {
            int size = infile.tellg();
            int cant = size / sizeof(structalquiler);
            Arreglo_Alquileres.resize(cant);
            infile.seekg(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
            {
                Arreglo_Alquileres[i].read(infile);
            }
            infile.close();
            
        }
    }

    void add(const Alquiler &x) {
        Arreglo_Alquileres.push_back(x);
        write();
    }

    bool write() {
        ofstream outfile(m_file_name.c_str(), ios::binary|ios::trunc);
        if (!outfile.is_open()) return false;
        int cant = Arreglo_Alquileres.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            Arreglo_Alquileres[i].save(outfile);
        }
        outfile.close();
        return true;
        
    }
};

int main() {
    
    Database base;

    vector<string> v = {"panuelo", "alpargatas", "chaleco"};
    Alquiler x(9,8,7,{6,5,4},{3,2,1},v);
    base.add(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just please don't use raw binary files these days. Serialize into text-files instead.

Comment: Remember that a `vector` will be nothing but a pointer to an array of data and some book-keeping to track the used size and the capacity. When you `write`, you literally write the contents of the object, and in this case that means the pointer and book-keeping. Not the data AT the pointer. Just the freaking address. And that address is useless in a file.

Comment: Also remember that C++ defines only the minimum size of an `int`, 16 bits, and leaves the rest floating. You don't know how big the `int` will be. You don't know how the bytes are ordered. If you read and write on the same machine with the same program that's not normally a problem, but if you move the file around to other machines or the writer is C++ and the reader is a different language, you can quickly find yourself in a world of hurt.

Comment: @Some there are many good reasons for using binary files, like for example a database. and ooh look, it's a database. not that i am saying that this code makes sense.

Comment: There is no way your file reading and writing would work.  The simple deductive reasoning -- the second parameter to `read` and `write` denotes how many bytes to read/write to/from the file.   What if `artlist` had 1000 characters in it?  You would need to tell the `read` and `write` function to read/write at least 1000 bytes.  What is the value of `int wo_size = sizeof(reg) - sizeof(reg.artlist);`?  It will never be 1000 (or more).  The `sizeof` is a compile-time value, never changes, regardless of how many characters you have in `artlist`.

Comment: Also, binary file reading/writing requires some up front work before even being considered.  Things like how the file will ultimately be layed out, where items will be placed within the file, etc.  For example, bytes 0 to 3 is the number of <x>.  An <x> is 12 bytes and start at byte 4.  The length of the artlist is a 4 byte value starting at byte 100, followed by the artlist, etc.  Then you write (and read) the file, following the layout.  Also, if you took the file you wrote and viewed it in a text editor, do you see any information that looks like you can recreate your objects?  I bet not.

Comment: *"I tried to compact it as much as possible"* -- that's a good start, but you could do more. You can make the code simpler by making your data simpler. *Does the problem persist if you remove the dates from `Alquiler`? If you remove the vector of strings? If you remove everything but the vector of strings?* Another tactic is to reduce the number of steps. Take a look at the file your code produces. If its contents match its expected contents, you could focus on reading the file; otherwise focus on writing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *"You would need to tell the `read` and `write` function to read/write at least 1000 bytes"* -- isn't that what is done by the lines `infile.read((char*)&read_size, sizeof(int));` and `outfile.write((char*)&size, sizeof(int));`?  The array is written as a size followed by that many entries. Similarly, each string is written as a size followed by the text (obtained from `.c_str()`, not from the address of the string object).

Answer (score 0):

I used a debugger to check your code as is step by step. And then I used a hex-editor to show the output.

And the result is: Your code, as shown, works fine.

But, if you use longer strings, then the `std::vector` in the `structalquiler` will have a variable length.

If you now want to read back the data, then you cannot calculate the number of elements from the filesize.

Example for Hex file after running the program as shown one time:
[image]

You can see that there is a padding of one `int` after the 9 data `int`s. But assuming that the program runs in the same environment, there should be no problem.

And this codes works fine. So, running the program 3 times it will give:
[image]

---

But now: What if we have longer string, then, we could get a file like this:

[image]

So,  `int cant = size / sizeof(structalquiler);` will not work any longer.

The solution is to read the file, record for record, until all data from the file will be consumed.

I will show you a quick fix, but you should consider a redesign.

The following will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int day, month, year;
};

struct structalquiler
{
    int dni, totalq, dep;
    int faday, famonth, fayear;
    int fdday, fdmonth, fdyear;
    vector<string> artlist;
};

class Alquiler {
private:

    int a_DNI_Cliente;
    int a_Total_Alquiler, a_Deposito;
    Date a_Date_Alquiler, a_Date_Devolucion;
    vector<string> a_Article_list;

public:

    Alquiler();
    Alquiler(int dni, int totalq, int dep, Date fa, Date fd, vector<string> arts);

    void save(ofstream& outfile) {                      // Bin file writing
        structalquiler reg;
        reg.dni = a_DNI_Cliente;
        reg.dep = a_Deposito;
        reg.totalq = a_Total_Alquiler;
        reg.faday = a_Date_Alquiler.day;
        reg.famonth = a_Date_Alquiler.month;
        reg.fayear = a_Date_Alquiler.year;
        reg.fdday = a_Date_Devolucion.day;
        reg.fdmonth = a_Date_Devolucion.month;
        reg.fdyear = a_Date_Devolucion.year;
        reg.artlist = a_Article_list;
        int sss1 = sizeof(reg);
        int sss2 = sizeof(reg.artlist);
        int wo_size = sizeof(reg) - sizeof(reg.artlist);

        outfile.write((char*)&reg, wo_size);

        int size = reg.artlist.size();              // Writing of the vector<string>
        outfile.write((char*)&size, sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int letter_amount = reg.artlist[i].length();
            outfile.write((char*)&letter_amount, sizeof(int));
            outfile.write(reg.artlist[i].c_str(), letter_amount);
        }

    }

    void read(ifstream& infile) {                           // Reading of the file
        structalquiler reg;
        int wo_size = sizeof(reg) - sizeof(reg.artlist);
        if (infile.read((char*)&reg, wo_size)) {

            a_DNI_Cliente = reg.dni;
            a_Deposito = reg.dep;
            a_Total_Alquiler = reg.totalq;
            a_Date_Alquiler.day = reg.faday;
            a_Date_Alquiler.month = reg.famonth;
            a_Date_Alquiler.year = reg.fayear;
            a_Date_Devolucion.day = reg.fdday;
            a_Date_Devolucion.month = reg.fdmonth;
            a_Date_Devolucion.year = reg.fdyear;
            // a_Article_list = reg.artlist;

            vector<string> v;                                   // Reading of the vector<string>
            int read_size;
            infile.read((char*)&read_size, sizeof(int));
            for (int i = 0; i < read_size; i++)
            {
                int letter_amount;
                infile.read((char*)&letter_amount, sizeof(int));
                char* buffer = new char[letter_amount + 1];
                infile.read(buffer, letter_amount);
                buffer[letter_amount] = '\0';
                v.push_back(string(buffer));
                delete[] buffer;

            }

            a_Article_list = v;
        }
    }


};

Alquiler::Alquiler() {}
Alquiler::Alquiler(int dni, int totalq, int dep, Date fa, Date fd, vector<string> arts)
    : a_DNI_Cliente(dni), a_Total_Alquiler(totalq), a_Deposito(dep), a_Date_Alquiler(fa), a_Date_Devolucion(fd), a_Article_list(arts) {}

class Database {
private:
    string m_file_name = "r:\\alquileres.dat";
    vector<Alquiler> Arreglo_Alquileres;
public:

    Database() {                                                                // storing in the vector<Alquiler>
        ifstream infile(m_file_name.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::ate);
        if (infile.is_open())
        {
            int size = infile.tellg();
            int ss2 = sizeof(structalquiler);
            int cant = size / sizeof(structalquiler);
            //Arreglo_Alquileres.resize(cant);
            infile.seekg(0);
            while (infile) {
                Arreglo_Alquileres.push_back({});
                Arreglo_Alquileres.back().read(infile);
            }
            if (not infile) Arreglo_Alquileres.pop_back();
            infile.close();

        }
    }

    void add(const Alquiler& x) {
        Arreglo_Alquileres.push_back(x);
        write();
    }

    bool write() {
        ofstream outfile(m_file_name.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::trunc);
        if (!outfile.is_open()) return false;
        int cant = Arreglo_Alquileres.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            Arreglo_Alquileres[i].save(outfile);
        }
        outfile.close();
        return true;

    }
};

int main() {

    Database base;

    vector<string> v = { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "alpargatas", "chaleco" };
    Alquiler x(9, 8, 7, { 6,5,4 }, { 3,2,1 }, v);
    base.add(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try this with much longer strings, not short strings.  You will see that this will fail to save the strings if the strings are longer.  A string has something called small-string-optimization, where the string is stored in an array -- anything above 16 or 20 characters, the memory is dynamically allocated, and the array is not used.  It looks like you fell into the trap that [this wrong code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reading-and-writing-binary-file-in-c-cplusplus) fell into.

Comment: You are right. There is indeed a problem in the line `int cant = size / sizeof(structalquiler);`. That is a bug. Need to debug again, why it worked in the first place . . .

Comment: @Peter Hey, thank you for spending your time with this. Yes, the problem is indeed in that line. The thing is that I'm trying to resize the vector<Alquiler> with the fixed size of the struct, but each struct will have a different size, because of its vector<string> being variable.

So the question would be, how can I resize the vector<Alquiler> correctly using the right size each time?

Comment: I drafted a solution for you. Please see my updated answer.